# bash cmdline tokenizer / relative frequency histogram... uniq fails

Tags: bash

I want to write this script in bash with command line utils, for fun.

```
# make the corpus
echo -e "this \t is   a \n cor-pus;  \nthis  \t\nis \n\t sparta. \n" > corpus.txt

# munge, collapse whitespace, tokenize
cat corpus.txt | tr -d '.!@#$%^&*()-_=+' | tr '\t' ' ' | tr '\n' ' ' | tr -s ' ' | fmt -1 | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

i expect

```
   2 this
   2 is
   1 a
   1 corpus
   1 sparta
```

but i get

```
   1 this
   1 is
   1 a
   1 corpus
   1 this
   1 is
   1 sparta
```

`uniq` fails when piped `fmt -1`. perhaps there are eof chars i don't see with `cat -e`? how does `uniq` decide what are lines and what are files?

`echo a a b | fmt -1 | uniq` does what i expect it too, so i don't know why the `... | fmt -1 | uniq | ...` in my script doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: `tr '\t' ' ' | tr '\n' ' ' | tr -s ' '` can be written `tr -s '\t\n' ' '`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to sort before you call `uniq`, as `uniq` expects its input to be sorted.  So:

```
< corpus.txt tr -d '.!@#$%^&*()-_=+' | tr -s '\t ' '\n' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Comment: ah, i only skimmed the man page. next time, i'll read every word!